# React Native : Dynamically Created TextBox value is not getting updated

Tags: reactjs, react-native, mobile

I'm little new to React Native. I have a scenario where I need to create the TextInput dynamically and bind values it from an array. Once the array updates, the value of the TextInput is not updating. Below is my code.

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
    textInputValues: [],
    textInput: [],
    samplearray://gets an array from the JSON
}

componentDidMount() {
    this.setTextInputValue();
    this.prepareTextBox();
}

setTextInputValue() {
  let textInputValues = this.state.textInputValues;
  this.state.samplearray.map(() => {
     textInputValues.push("") //default value
     this.setState({ textInputValues })
  })
}

prepareTextBox() {
let textInput = this.state.textInput;
this.state.samplearray.map((value, index) => {
    textInput.push(<TextInput style={styles.textBox} value={this.state.textInputValues[index]}  key={index} />);
})
this.setState({ textInput })}
```

Code to render the TextBox in the render method.

```
  {  this.state.textInput.map((value, index) => {
                        return value
  })}
```

I have button on which **this.state.textInputValues** array value gets changed. But change of that is not being reflected in the TextInput. Stuck with this since 2 days. Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how your code block should look (do read the comments for explanation):

```
 componentDidMount() {
      this.setTextInputValue();
      // call the below function from `setTextInputValue` as you have dependency on that
      // this.prepareTextBox();
  }

  setTextInputValue() {
    let textInputValues = [...this.state.textInputValues];
    this.state.samplearray.map((value) => {
       textInputValues = [ ...textInputValues , value] //default value

       // this is how you should call `prepareTextBox`
       // in setState callback as it will confirm that state is updated
       this.setState({ textInputValues },() => {
          this.prepareTextBox();
       })
    })
  }

  prepareTextBox() {
    let textInput = [...this.state.textInput];
    this.state.samplearray.map((value, index) => {
        textInput.push(<input value={this.state.textInputValues[index]}  key={index} />);
    })
    this.setState({ textInput })
  }
```

---

You can run the below snippet and check, hope that will clear your doubts :

```js
const { useState , useEffect } = React;

class App extends React.Component {
  
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
      textInputValues: [],
      textInput: [],
      samplearray:["Vivek","Darshita"]//gets an array from the JSON
      }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
      this.setTextInputValue();
  }

  setTextInputValue() {
    let textInputValues = [...this.state.textInputValues];
    this.state.samplearray.map((value) => {
       textInputValues = [ ...textInputValues , value] //default value
       this.setState({ textInputValues },() => {
          this.prepareTextBox();
       })
    })
  }

  prepareTextBox() {
    let textInput = [...this.state.textInput];
    this.state.samplearray.map((value, index) => {
        textInput.push(<input value={this.state.textInputValues[index]}  key={index} />);
    })
    this.setState({ textInput })
  }

  changeValues = () => {
    this.setState({
      textInput : [],
      textInputValues : ["New - Vivek" , "New - Darshita"]
    },() => {
      this.prepareTextBox();
    });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        { this.state.textInput }
        <button onClick={this.changeValues}>Change Value</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
  
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('react-root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react-root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you add button click event in the snippet, which will update the value of textInputValues array and thus update the Input box ? I tried calling a sample event called TestFunc() which updates the value of array textInputValues but the value of text input is unaltered.

Comment: thank you so much for your time. The main mistake that I was doing was, in the button click event, I was not setting calling prepareTextBox method and I was not initializing the textInput array to empty.

Comment: @Vasanth, glad to know, it hepled, please also accept the answer.

Comment: I'm facing one problem with the above solution. Since we refreshing the textInput array on a button click, if there are lot of text boxes, then refreshing of it is introducing a delay in the UI. Which is not acceptable. Rather refreshing entire set of Textbox/Input can we just refresh the state variable that it point too ?

Comment: @Vasanth, yes for that you have to find and match and update the array